# Generated Signed Bundle / APK doesn't work

Tags: java, android, bundle

I can't generated signed `bundle` / `apk` in `Android Studio`.
When I cliked on it, I have this error : **File '`root/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar`' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.**

Like this post : [Android Studio3.2 APK Build Error -> reserved file or directory name 'lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52528509/android-studio3-2-apk-build-error-reserved-file-or-directory-name-lib) , I try to put in my gradle file :

```
implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

but it doens't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try to replace `api` with `implimentation`

Comment: This is a strange maven coords for apache commons io. Why not use the official release: `implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'`?

Comment: I can try. How can I included this in my graddle file ?
It return error :
startup failed:
build file '/app/build.gradle': 48: Statement labels may not be used in build scripts.
In case you tried to configure a property named 'group', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.
 @ line 48, column 12.
       group: implementation 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
              ^

1 error

Open File

Comment: I tried like this :  implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6' but i have the same error

Comment: I have same problem with implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'

Comment: Check your project for .jar files. It would assume that there is at least one jar file in a lib folder which causes the conflict.

Comment: Hi have dir Gradle:commons-io:commons-io:2.4@jar -> commons-io-2.4.jar library root -> {META-INF , org.apache.commons.io} -> ...  I delete it ?